# How to write pid file after uid is set in upstart config file

Tags: linux, pid, upstart

currently I need to start a java application from upstart file and monitor it with monit, but needs a pid file.

I set the application user to be wwww-data:adm using

```
setuid www-data    
setgid adm
```

and then

```
script  
    echo $$ > /var/run/logstash.pid  
    exec java -jar logstash.jar agent -f logstash.conf --log logstash.stdout  
end script
```

error log shows that

```
/proc/self/fd/9: 2: /proc/self/fd/9: cannot create /var/run/logstash.pid: Permission denied
```

How can I write the pid file?

ps. I used start-stop-daemon and it tells "can not create Java Virtual Machine"

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it by adding a folder owned by www-data:adm in **/var/run** and put pid file there.

Comment: but isn't `/var/run` lost at reboot ?

Answer (score 0):

Files and directories in /run and /var/run are not persistent across reboot.

Workaround - We can solve this by making a sub-directory every time a system comes up, via init scripts.

I guess monit does not have an inbuilt solution to solve this.
I would like to know the ideal solution for this, if someone comes up.